# Why does update-grub not find ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, grub2, windows-7, bootloader

I've recently installed Ubuntu onto my laptop.

With the intention of dual booting with Windows 7.

On installation Grub wasn't loading, the computer continued to boot straight into windows.

I loaded a live cd, mounted the installed Ubuntu partition (sda6) as `/mnt/` and windows boot partition as `/mnt/boot`

Following the second option [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7).

Through its entirety, so creating a new `grub.cfg` file.

```
chroot /mnt update-grub
```

Did not find Ubuntu, just Windows 7 and the Windows recovery partition. Thinking this might be a weird quirk that as I was in Ubuntu (all be it a Live CD) it might not list Ubuntu I restarted. Grub loaded but Ubuntu was nowhere to be seen.

How can I add Ubuntu with Grub2?  I could have fixed this myself in old grub but I'm pretty much in the dark here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2) of the [Ubuntu community GRUB 2 documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) lists other methods of reinstalling GRUB2 to your Master Boot Record. One of them will likely be effective. I recommend that you try the [Boot-Repair graphical tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Use_Boot-Repair_Graphical_Tool).

Comment: Thank you, this didn't quite work though as this wouldn't allow me to install grub onto the windows boot partition.

But I did install it again onto the ubuntu partion and then copied the "grub.cfg" file to the grub install that I'd already achieved on the windows boot partition and it worked perfectly.  Might have issues with future kernel updates though, I suspect.